# Airflow: chaining tasks in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, airflow

I am currently working on a DAG that requires monthly looping over a long list of tasks.

To achieve this, I create an empty list and then loop over several tasks, changing their task_ids according to a new month.

Example:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.utils.helpers import chain

dag = DAG(
    "import_trx_table",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="45 9 * * *",
)

task_list = []

for month_ds in month_lst_ds:
    start = DummyOperator(task_id=f"dummy_start_trx_table_imports_{month_ds}", dag=dag)

    task_list.append(start)

...

chain(*task_list)
```

The issue is that the DAG is extremely long (and slow) now (since I iterate for more than 12 months). Some of these tasks could definitely be running in parallel.

I tried to check if the chain helper function had a way of chaining in parallel but couldn't find anything.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add a sketch how do you expect the DAG to look like in the ui? Is there any dependency between months or all months can run in parallel?

Comment: There are no dependencies between the months. They can in fact all run at the same time as the tasks are writing to monthly partitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `chain` but it doesn't really give value here.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2021, 6, 7),
}

dag = DAG(
    "stackoverflow_question",
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval="@daily",
)

month_lst_ds = ['Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov']

start_op = DummyOperator(task_id='start_task', dag=dag)
end_op = DummyOperator(task_id='end_task', dag=dag)
for month_ds in month_lst_ds:
    month_op = DummyOperator(task_id=f"dummy_start_trx_table_imports_{month_ds}", dag=dag)
    start_op >> month_op >> end_op
```

If you wish you can replace

```
start_op >> month_op >> end_op
```

with

```
chain(start_op, month_op, end_op )
```

This is how the DAG structure looks in the graph view:

[image]

Comment: This looks very good. I tried it with my DAG but once the start_op finished the whole run also gets marked as successful and doesn't go through the actual monthly tasks. Any idea why?

Comment: That's another question that is not related to the DAG structure... for that please post your real code in a new question. Your code is probably not DummyOperators

Comment: @ArturoBelano I have occasionally had issues with omissions from massively-parallel structures like this, but assumed those were related to either the Airflow version or limits on Airflow's parallel processing.  Elad is right that debugging the structure should be a separate question, unless the structure he displayed is substantially different from what you intended.

Comment: @SarahMesser that's a valid point. Elad's answer is correct. Thanks for the help!