# Run multiple tasks in parallel

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I know it is possible to run 1 set of tasks in parallel. For example, something like this:

```
begin >> [A, B, C, D,E] >> end
```

would run A, B, C, D, E all in parallel. However, I want to do something like this such that after **begin**, there are two workflows running in parallel. Something like:

```
            A -> B -> C 
begin ->                    ->  end
            D -> E -> F
```

What would be the correct syntax to achieve this?

Comment: the draw and the example are a bit different. do you want to run a,b,c in parallel with d,e,f ? or after a to run b,c,d and d,e,f ? in that case I have problem with d that is at both

Comment: I want to run (C after B after A) In parallel to (F after E after D). Meaning 2 flows running in parallel but within each flow, they should run sequentially @ozs

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/64862958/14624409 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67889657/14624409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every split is like a starting point.

```
start_dag = start_task()
end_dag = end_task()

a = DummyOperator(task_id="a")
b = DummyOperator(task_id="b")
c = DummyOperator(task_id="c")
d = DummyOperator(task_id="d")
e = DummyOperator(task_id="e")
f = DummyOperator(task_id="f")

(start_dag >> [a, d])
(a >> b >> c >> end_dag)
(d >> e >> f >> end_dag)
```

[image]